# Load custom fields in post-content/single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I got from a client product descriptions in an excel/csv file. It looks like the following:

> product name; product description; price; tags; shop location

I am thinking of creating a post template and fill the template with custom fields, with the plugin [CSV Import for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/).

Any suggestions how to add custom fields to my `single.php` file and load them with the proper value of the post? Or is there an easier solution to modify the post `content`and load custom fields?

I appreciate an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating custom fields I almost always use the Advanced Custom Fields (or ACF) plugin. Widely spread plugin, a lot of other plugins work well with it (importers!)
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com

For importing I usually use WP All Import (http://www.wpallimport.com).

Sorry, that I do not write an example here - but the two plugins I suggest have a lot of examples and tutorials! :D

I am not affiliated with any of them - only a satisfied user.

Comment: How are you displaying custom fields in a post?

Comment: Depends on the solution you use. With ACF you can find example here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/. Every other solution for custom fields have their own way of inserting the values in a post. If you would like an exact answer for your case, you should include example code in your question :)